# Remove parentheses from nested list created from loop Python

Tags: python, list, loops, parentheses

Please, do you know how to remove a parentheses'(', ')' from this code?

```
values_list = [] 
x = 0
for n in different_values:
   for each  in different_values:
      different_id = list((different_values))
      arg_1 = different_id[x]
      cursor.execute(sqlstmt2,arg_1=arg_1)
      rows = ((cursor.fetchmany(each)))
      index += 1
      x += 1
      print(rows)
      values_list.append(rows)
      break

print((values_list))
```

OUTPUT IS:

```
[[(105, 'David', '05.11.88', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k')], [(106, 'Valli', '16.06.89', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k')]]
```

I want to create nested list like a parameter for insert function to Google Sheet, but outside the loop.

```
wks.insert_rows(row=1, number=1, values=values_list)
```

Comment: why the double `(())` on your code? `((cursor.fetchmany(each)))`, `list((different_values))`

Comment: Do you want a list of list as your output?

Comment: OK, I rolled-back the edit to keep the `((()))`

Comment: I forgot to delete double (()) pararentheses, but I want to this output:
[[105, 'David', '05.11.88', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k'], [106, 'Valli', '16.06.89', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k']]

Comment: @ajaysingh - exactly list of list as output

Comment: @JardaJaromir what is the code doing? You're looping through `different values` twice, then you never use `n`, rename `different_values` to `different_id` and then get the `x`th index which is `each` anyway. Then you `break` out of the inner loop after one iteration... `index` is never defined and never used. You really need to go back and think about your logic.

Comment: Can you also give us some example data to work with?

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do with your code, add comments and sample input or intermediate results.

Comment: I am looping through different_id list and load each different_id into arg_1

and this arg_1 i am using  as paramether in sql where clause.

sqlstmt2 = "select * from legislators where id in:arg_1"

then I want to select all rows with different_id (compare between ID's in Oracle database and ID's from Google Sheets)

and this rows insert into Google Sheets. I had this "worksheet.insert_row(rows,index)" inide loop, but it was slow.

Now I want to create list of list and use it in this code:
wks.insert_rows(row=1, number=1, values=values_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `[[(a, b, c)], [(d, e, f)]]` is a list of two entries which are each a list of one entry which is a tuple of three entries, namely `a`, `b`, and `c` — or `d`, `e`, and `f`.  So If you want to "get rid" of a pair of parentheses, you mean that you want to get what's inside them.  This is done by indexing the one and only element for lists and tuples:

```
print(values_list)
[[(105, 'David', '05.11.88', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k')],
 [(106, 'Valli', '16.06.89', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k')]]
print([ value[0] for value in values_list ])
[(105, 'David', '05.11.88', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k'),
 (106, 'Valli', '16.06.89', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k')]
```

The result then is a list of tuples (instead of a list of lists of tuples), hence one pair of parentheses has been removed.

If you want to keep the brackets and remove the (round) parentheses instead, you can just convert the tuples to lists:

```
print([ list(value[0]) for value in values_list ])
[[105, 'David', '05.11.88', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k'],
 [106, 'Valli', '16.06.89', 'M', 'xxx', 'United States of America', 'republican', 'k']]
```

But I guess it would be better not to create the original structure in the first place:

```
rows = list(cursor.fetchmany(each)[0])
```

This of course assumes that your `fetchmany()` call will always only return exactly one entry (represented by a tuple).  With this code you will get the one single entry of of the results list and convert it (the tuple) to a list.

I cannot say if these premises are true in your case.  You should consider that before applying my code proposal.

Comment: This solved the immediate problem, but doesn't address the serious problem of wtf is that double loop doing and who allowed it to exist?

Comment: I guess the `fetchmany()` call returns a list of entries, represented by tuples, and in this particular case always exactly one result (due to proper filtering), still packed in a list.  Hence the list of a tuple.

Comment: About the double loop:  Actually my best guess would be that this is a copy/paste error and the original code doesn't have that in this way (I guess one of the `different_values` is incorrect).  The shown current output suggests that.

Comment: @Alfie except it has a `break` which is encountered every time. `for _ in a: for _ in a: f(); break` is the same as `for _ in a: f()`.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't take that into account.  Since there is no `continue` anywhere in the code, that seems to be not the optimal way of expressing the thought.  Still — the task at hand was not to fix all flaws in the code; it seems to have produced the desired output, just not in the desired format.  To remove the tuple parentheses was my aim and that's what my answer explains.